# Qt Quick, SQLITE - how to bind multiple views to one model / (multiple models with one db)

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qml

I'm struggling with following scenario:

- I have one QML with a ListView containing all the students in SQL db
- I also have another QML file which contains a Page with details of any selected student.

When user clicks on one of the entries in the list he's being moved (using StackView) to the second QML with all the details.

On the details page the user is able to modify the data and save it. The problem is that after doing that, the list is not being refreshed (e.g. when user adds a new student there is no new entry on the list).

The reason behind this is that when I open the DetailsPage, I'm delibarately creating a new model with access to the same table in SQL. When I then submit the changes, the new model gets updated but not the old one (the one connected with the list). So when I come back to the list it still holds the old data.

Now I'm looking for a way to fix it, I have some ideas but I'm not sure which of them is the best solution (maybe none):

- one thing I tried was to reuse the very same model across multiple views. It didn't really work since in the DetailsPage I need to see only these rows that match the selected student. So I would need to filter it, but how? By setting a model property (I've seen that in one of the tutorials)? How would I reset it later back to the initial state?
- Another idea is to create a different model for the DetailsPage and after submiting changes (possibly while popping the page from the StackView), notify the previous model about the changes and force it to emit the dataChanged signal. But again - I don't really know how to do it.

At the moment the model in StudentList is declared like that:

```
SqlDb {
    id: sqlModel
    onDataChanged: {
        console.log("TROLO")
    }
}
```

So there nothing inside it really. When opening the DetailsPage, I need to specify the name to filter the results so it looks like that:

```
Layout.fillHeight: true
SqlDb {
    id: sql_model
    name: studentName
    onDataChanged: {
        console.log("TRALA")
    }
}
```

When submiting changes I got "TRALA" printed but not "TROLO".

I was mostly using this official Qt tutorial
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-chattutorial-example.html